# gensim doc2vec train more documents from pre-trained model

Tags: gensim, doc2vec, pre-trained-model, resuming-training

I am trying to train with new labelled document(TaggedDocument) with the pre-trained model.

Pretrained model is the trained model with documents which the unique id with label1_index, for instance, Good_0, Good_1 to Good_999
And the total size of trained data is about 7000

Now, I want to train the pre-trained model with new documents which the unique id with label2_index, for instance, Bad_0, Bad_1... to Bad_1211
And the total size of trained data is about 1211

The train itself was successful without any error, but the problem is that whenever I try to use 'most_similar' it only suggests the similar document labelled with Good_... where I expect the labelled with Bad_.

If I train altogether from the beginning, it gives me the answers I expected - it infers a newly given document similar to either labelled with Good or Bad.

However, the practice above will not work as the one trained altogether from the beginning.

Is continuing train not working properly or did I make some mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gensim `Doc2Vec` class can always be fed extra examples via `train()`, but it only discovers the working vocabulary of both word-tokens and document-tags during an initial `build_vocab()` step. So unless words/tags were available during the `build_vocab()`, they'll be ignored as unknown later. (The words get silently dropped from the text; the tags aren't trained or remembered inside the model.)

The `Word2Vec` superclass from which `Doc2Vec` borrows a lot of functionality has a newer, more-experimental parameter on its `build_vocab()` called `update`. If set true, that call to `build_vocab()` will add to, rather than replace, any prior vocabulary. However, as of February 2018, this option doesn't yet work with `Doc2Vec`, and indeed often causes memory-fault crashes.

But even if/when that can be made to work, providing incremental training examples isn't necessarily a good idea. By only updating parts of the model – those exercised by the new examples – the overall model can get worse, or its vectors made less self-consistent with each other. (The essence of these dense-embedding models is that the optimization over *all* varied examples results in generally-useful vectors. Training over just some subset causes the model to drift towards being good on just that subset, at likely cost to earlier examples.)

If you need new examples to also become part of the results for `most_similar()`, you might want to create your own separate set-of-vectors outside of `Doc2Vec`. When you infer new vectors for new texts, you could add those to that outside set, and then implement your own `most_similar()` (using the gensim code as a model) to search over this expanding set of vectors, rather than just the fixed set that is created by initial bulk `Doc2Vec` training.

Comment: You answered clearly but in long way. You're saying that train for new labels and ids will not work on top of pre-trained model. Did I understand correctly?

Plus, what you wrote above is somewhat different than the one instructed on the gensim website. It says that when you pass parameter update=True then new words maybe trained as well . . . Although I am not sure if it is really working as they instructed.

Comment: Correct: new calls to `train()` won't allow any new words/tags to be learned. It's only the `build_vocab()` step that establishes the vocabulary, & (as noted in my answer) the `update=True` option that works for some `Word2Vec` models hasn't yet been fixed to work for `Doc2Vec`. (And even if/when it is fixed, using it may not be wise/reliable because incremental training with partial datasets introduces a lot of other complications/tradeoffs.)

Comment: Thank you for your help!